# How to find current employee fee based on name and date from a different sheet

Tags: google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a spreadsheet with all employees work reports with info about time spent on a job and other details.
I can't figure out how to get the fee the employee is supposed to get paid because I can either set the employee's fee manually for every single entry (not desirable) or there should be a formula that could automatically grab that data for me

Basically what I have in mind is some (maybe?) Arrayformula that for every date in the employee report entry searches for the matching hourly fee that fits the date the fee has been updated but when there is another fee update, it won't affect the older fees

[image: Employee fees sheet]

[image: Reports overview per employee]

I have tried VLOOKUP with ARRAYFORMULA but I could only get the latest fee and that is not good because that would also change the payments for older entries

EDIT: forgot to provide a link to a dummy sheet with the scenario mentioned
[DUMMY sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IqaEta8ARv_C_4_MR9VxWDw2KMhudHLmif1_OKRkIss)

Comment: hI - can you comment in english what is the logic that you want out of your spreadsheet. iT shoud lookup the fee table, and if there is an exact date match, it should copy the value from the table. If there is not, what should happen?

Comment: Hello, if an employee has a set fee starting today I want the ongoing fee to be the current one from this day but for older periods there should still be the previous fee set until the recent change.
Example:
fee starting Jan 2021 was 20 
fee sarting Aug 2022 is 25

So I just add the new date and price in the Fees sheet and the overview per employee will be automatically counting the correct fees regarding date. Automated formula like ARRAYFORMULA is highly prioritized because there will be even more than one entry per employee per day

Comment: I added hopefully enough info in the Employee1 sheet with my formula that I thought might be aiming the correct direction but my knowledge ends there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use something among those lines:

`=vlookup(D5;Fees!$C$2:$D$4;2)`

make sure your fees table dates are in ascending order. I just removed the (;FALSE) as the last argument and it worked (don't ask me why)

Comment: I just added the ARRAYFORMULA =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D;Fees!$C$2:$D$4;2)))


and it works exactly as needed! I love how sometimes it seems like a more difficult formula to make but the solution is just nice and simple. I am forever grateful for your help